# Is there a unique vector field with given field lines?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If given a vector field I know what differential equation to set up in order to find the field lines. What about the opposite question?

Specifically, is there a unique vector field (up to scalar multiple) that will give me field lines of the form $x^2 + 4y^2 = C$?

Clearly $F = (-8y, \thinspace 2x)$ and any scalar multiple of this vector field will give me those field lines. Are there any more, and if so, can I find them all?

Comment: Differentiating with respect to time gives $2x\dot{x}+8y\dot{y}=0$. ANY field $F=(\dot{x},\dot{y})$ satisfying this equation will work. For example, $F=(xy,-x^2/4)$. This is obviously not a scalar multiple of your $F$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector field is not uniquely defined. For example instead of taking  scalar multiple of your F, take a different scalar on each level set (i.e. on each  ellipse) and multiply those with your F.

EDIT: even more general you can vary the scalar even within each level set. This gives you another valid field if the scalar function (function of a parametrization of the level set) satisfies the so called admissibility condition that it is continuous and between any two of its zeroes its inverse integrates to infinity on both sides